# CNN is overfitting to minority class

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I'm new to developing CNNs and currently making a binary image classifier using PyTorch. My dataset was heavily unbalanced, and I've manually augmented my a testing split and training split to be balanced. I have a class 0 (Training set has 6500 images), and class 1 (training set has 5200ish images). When I try to use skorch's fit function, I get a validation accuracy equivalent to the percent of class 1 images in the set, and my prediction function only outputs 1 for all images.

This is the tutorial I adapted my CNN from: https://colab.research.google.com/github/dnouri/skorch/blob/master/notebooks/Transfer_Learning.ipynb#scrollTo=cane7VRWW3dO

Here's my CNN: (it's adapted from a tutorial)

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
import torchvision.models as models
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
import pandas as pd
from skorch import NeuralNetClassifier
from skorch.helper import predefined_split
from skorch.callbacks import LRScheduler
from skorch.callbacks import Checkpoint
from skorch.callbacks import Freezer

from PIL import Image
import skorch
import os
import cv2
import glob

from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, Normalizer
#Define transforms (will be same w/o online transforms)
#Manually augmented earlier
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    #transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
    #transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                         [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

val_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    #transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                         [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

train_ds = datasets.ImageFolder(train_split_path, train_transforms)
val_ds = datasets.ImageFolder(test_aug_split_path, val_transforms)

checkpoint = Checkpoint(
    f_params='best_model.pt', monitor='valid_acc_best')

#Using ResNet with some layers for now
class PretrainedModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, output_features):
        super().__init__()
        model = models.resnet152(pretrained=True)
        #Don't want to change pretrained weights
        for param in model.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False

        num_features = model.fc.in_features
        fc_layers = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(num_features, 4096),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                nn.Dropout(p=0.3),
                nn.Linear(4096, output_features),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                nn.Dropout(p=0.3),
            )
        model.fc = fc_layers

        self.model = model

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)

use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()

net = NeuralNetClassifier(
    module=PretrainedModel,
    module__output_features = 2,
    criterion=nn.CrossEntropyLoss,
    batch_size = 16,
    lr=0.0001,
    max_epochs=3,
    optimizer=optim.Adam,
    train_split=predefined_split(val_ds),
    callbacks=[checkpoint],
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
)

net.fit(train_ds, y=None)
```

Here are the results of the fit function:

Epoch 1: Train loss = .46 Valid_acc = .4301 Valid Loss = .6931

Epoch 2: Train loss = .6931 Valid_acc = .4301 Valid Loss = .6931

Epoch 3: Train loss = .6931 Valid_acc = .4301 Valid Loss = .6931

As it turns out for this particular dataset, exactly 43% of my validation images are Class 1 images.

y_pred = net.predict(val_ds) gives me the following:

array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)

I guess I have two questions:

1) Is there anything that I have done incorrectly in my initialization of my CNN that would cause this?

2) What would cause this, and is there anything I can do to correct for it?

Comment: Could you include your import statements and/or possibly a link to the tutorial from which you adapted your code?

Comment: I've edited both in!

Comment: do you shuffle your training examples?

Comment: Yes, good point - I had an array of all my images that I shuffled before I manually split the images.

Comment: The last dropout layer seems odd. Usually you do not put Dropout as the very last layer of a net.

Comment: I found out the error was that I needed to add a shuffler to my iterator! I think it was because ImageFolder flows images in by class label folders.